# How to calculate means and errors of intrinsically correlated runs?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means, standard-error

I am currently simulating a molecule and need to calculate the global mean value and more specifically the error of the global mean of a parameter $r$ denoting its size. To do that I have a multiple of $N=10$ runs, each having $n=10.000$ data points $r_i^j$ - where an upper index denotes the run and a lower the data point inside run $j$. Due to the "high" sampling frequency I can assure that there is correlation between the data points $r_i$ in a given run. That is why i think I cannot use the answer given in a similar question ([Calculating statistic for multiple runs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157282/calculating-statistic-for-multiple-runs?newreg=b78f51648cf44b52af28cd0dbb4503ed)).
So my questions are:

1.) Does the correlation really make a difference in calculating the error of the global mean value?

2.) If so what is the correct way to compute the global mean?

By discussion with colleagues I think the appropriate way would be to calculate the $\bar{r}^j$ and $\sigma^j$ for each run and then look at the distribution of $\bar{r}^j$ to calculate its standard deviation and standard error.

Comment: I'd say maybe read something about what the 'effective sample size' is.

Comment: Didn't had that on my radar, thanks. Still, how am I combining all the samples?

Comment: Let's try to understand your model. Do you believe that the samples from different runs are independent and the samples in the same run have correlations depending essentially just on the time difference?

Comment: Yes, exactly. All runs start with a random configuration of the same type of molecule and evolve in time. I checked it and different runs are **not** correlated and a single run is autocorrelated on small timescales, i.e. correlation falls to $e^{-1}$ after maximal $2.5 n$ timesteps.

Comment: I am sorry. I mean $0.025n$ timesteps.

Comment: Best estimate for the mean is to use all samples, and average those. This will always be best. The effective sample size tells how variable the average is. If everything is independent, then the effective sample size is equal to your sample size. If everything is perfectly dependent, i.e., equal to each other, the effective sample size is 1, and in any uncertainty analysis the sample should be treated as it is of size 1.